# Symfony 5 - identical forms in CreateFormBuilder constructor

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I’m trying to create several identical forms, but it turns out that the forms are the same, or rather their **values are the same**, thus only the value of the first form changes

```
    foreach ($projectStages as $projectStage) {
        $formStage = $this->createFormBuilder($projectStage)
            ->add('status', ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'choices' => [
                        'active' => true,
                        'not active' => false,
                    ]

                ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Set active ' . $projectStage->getTitle()));

        $forms[$projectStage->getId()] = $formStage->getForm();
        $forms[$projectStage->getId()]->handleRequest($request);
        if ($forms[$projectStage->getId()]->isSubmitted()) {
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect('/update-project/' . $id);
        }
        $forms[$projectStage->getId()] = $forms[$projectStage->getId()]->createView();
    }
```

in twig i did this

```
{% for formStage in formStages %}
    {{ form_start(formStage) }}
    {{ form_widget(formStage.status) }}
    {{ form_end(formStage) }}
{% endfor %}
```

[what is displayed in
HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhL0j.jpg)

Comment: With what you are showing, you are creating independent forms and only one will be submitted when you press the button.  I think you want to use a CollectionType assuming you want to be able to update multiple stages at the same time.